# Motion of a charged particle in a "solid" charged sphere (accounting for radiation)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, newtonian-mechanics, classical-electrodynamics

> Consider a particle (point charge) with charge $q$ and mass $m$ that crosses into a uniformly charged sphere (with charge $Q$ and radius $R$). The trajectory of the particle is a diameter of the sphere, and when it crosses the surface of the sphere it has a velocity $\mathbf{v_0}$. Assuming the particle only interacts electromagnetically with the sphere, and considering Larmor's radiation formula, what is the motion of the particle?

First I have to find the electric field $\mathbf{E}$ and the potential $\varphi$ inside the sphere. This can be done easily with Gauss' law, and I obtain:

$$\mathbf{E}=\frac{Q}{4\pi \epsilon_0 R^3}r\mathbf{\hat{r}} $$

Let $k=Q/4\pi\epsilon_0 R^3$, so $\mathbf{E}=kr\mathbf{\hat{r}}$. To find the potential, I consider spherical symmetry so $\mathbf{E}=-\frac{\mathrm{d}\varphi}{\mathrm{d}r}\mathbf{\hat{r}} $, therefore:

$$\varphi = -\frac{kr^2}{2}$$

The energy of the particle is:

$$\mathcal{E}=\frac{1}{2}m\dot{r}^2-\frac{qkr^2}{2} $$

And Larmor's formula is:

$$P=\frac{q^2\ddot{r}^2}{6\pi\epsilon_0 c^3}=-\frac{\mathrm{d}\mathcal{E}}{\mathrm{d}t}$$

So we have:

$$\frac{q^2\ddot{r}^2}{6\pi\epsilon_0 c^3}=-m\dot{r}\ddot{r}-qkr\dot{r}$$

Now, according to Newton's third law, and considering that the particle only moves radially:

$$m\ddot{r}=qE=qkr$$

Substituting $\ddot{r}$, I get (setting $L=1/6\pi\epsilon_0 c^3$):

$$q^2Lq^2k^2\frac{r^2}{m^2}=-2qkr\dot{r}$$

(Oh, the $L$ has nothing to do with angular momentum, I just called it $L$ for Larmor (as in the big constant in Larmor's formula). Anyway! I get:

$$\dot{r}+\frac{q^3Lk}{2m^2}r=0$$

This equation has the solution:

$$r(t)=r_0\exp\left(-\frac{q^3Lk}{2m^2}t\right)$$

This makes sense, I guess? Until I consider the sign of the constant inside the exponential. If $q$ and $Q$ have opposite signs, I would assume that the particle falls, but it doesn't. Also I find it peculiar that this solution doesn't depend on the initial velocity $\mathbf{v_0}$. So the trajectory always decays and never actually crosses the center, regardless of the initial speed? I know there's something I'm missing. What's wrong here?

EDIT: I think the problem with the particle shooting away instead of falling in has to do with me setting the Larmor radiation $P=-\frac{\mathrm{d}\mathcal{E}}{\mathrm{d}t}$. However, from the formula, $P\geq 0$, and radiation makes a particle *lose* energy, hence why I set it as the negative of the derivative of energy. There must be something else.

---

EDIT, EPISODE 2:

Okay, so [Floris](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/26969/floris) noted that that Newton step:

$$m\ddot{r}=qE=qkr$$

Was not accurate, because it assumes that the acceleration of the particle is *only* due to the electric field, while clearly the loss of energy through radiation must also change the kinetic energy of the particle, thereby causing some kind of acceleration.

So, disregard Newton and acquire another differential equation from $P=-\frac{\mathrm{d}\mathcal{E}}{\mathrm{d}t}$:

$$q^2 L \ddot{r}^2 + m\dot{r}\ddot{r} -qkr\dot{r}=0$$

Or rather,

$$\ddot{r}^2 + \frac{m}{q^2L}\dot{r}\ddot{r} -\frac{k}{qL}r\dot{r}=0$$

This is a quadratic on $\ddot{r}$, so I uh...

$$\ddot{r}=-\frac{m}{2q^2L}\dot{r} \pm \sqrt{\frac{m^2}{4q^4L^2}\dot{r}^2+\frac{k}{qL}r\dot{r}} $$

This is assuming, of course, that the thing inside the square root is non-negative. So, now this became a differential equations problem. That equation is non-linear, and it doesn't allow the usual linearization method since the critical points are $\dot{r}=0$, and at that point the derivative $\frac{\mathrm{d}\ddot{r}}{\mathrm{d}\dot{r}}$ doesn't exist. How does one solve that equation? Or perhaps not solve but just gain insight on the system?

Comment: How do you figure the "according to Newton's third law" part - the radial acceleration is not simply a function of position because of the radiative losses no?

Comment: @Floris True, that is probably the problem. Newton's third law should read something like ma=qE+F, where F is an effective force due to radiation. Maybe don't even consider Newton's law at all and just try to solve for P=-dE/dt.

Comment: Yes - just drop that Newton step in the middle; otherwise you seem to be on the right track.

Comment: Just a minor note, I think you missed the vacuum permittivity in the electric field.

Comment: @IvanLerner yep. I'll fix it.

Comment: The assignment in the yellow box is ill-conceived. There is no unique way to account for the interaction of uniformly charged medium with a massive particle of non-zero dimensions. Electrostatic field of the sphere is not sufficient as friction and other additional forces due to the medium are present. There is no definite specification of these in the assignment.

Comment: @JánLalinský The problem is under the assumption that the mass is a point mass and that it only interacts electrically with the sphere. There are no other forces in consideration.

Comment: For point particles, the Poynting theorem and the Larmor formula based on it cannot be derived in a valid way - electric field is not defined at the position of the particle. So energy losses cannot be calculated reliably based on Larmor's formula. Only if the particle has finite charge density, the Poynting theorem and Larmor formula can be applied. For extended particles, however, the collision of the particle with the particles forming the electrized medium of the sphere need to be taken into account. There is no such thing as electric charge without material particles carrying it.